# Eclipse RCP: Action "RESET_PERSPECTIVE" shows previously hidden menu entries

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Due to a migration from Eclipse 3.0 to 4.4, it was necessary to hide unnecessary menu entries like "open file" and "key assist".

I hide those by calling `hideActionSet` in my `postWindowOpen` method

```
public void postWindowOpen(IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer)
{       
    IWorkbenchWindow[] windows = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows();

    for(int i = 0; i < windows.length; ++i)
    {
        IWorkbenchPage page = windows[i].getActivePage();
        if(page != null)
        {
            page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.keyBindings");
                page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.openFiles");
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine so far. But when rearrange my perspective, then reset the perspective and then change to another perspective, the unnecessary menu entries show up again.

I tried fixing this by calling the same code in my `perspectiveActivated` and `perspectiveChanged` methods. The methods `hideActionSet` are reached, but they don't have an effect.

Here are those two methods:

```
public void perspectiveActivated(IWorkbenchPage page, IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective) 
{
    if( perspective.getId().equals(m_PerspektivenID) || m_PerspektivenID.equals(STANDARDAKTION))
    {
        setEnabled( true );
    }
    else
    {
        setEnabled( false );
    }

    if(page != null)
    {
        page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.keyBindings");
        page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.openFiles");
    }
}

public void perspectiveChanged(IWorkbenchPage page, IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective, String changeId) 
{
    if(changeId.equals(IWorkbenchPage.CHANGE_RESET_COMPLETE))
    {
        if(page != null)
        {
            page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.openFiles");
            page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.keyBindings");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could look at using the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point to hide things rather than code.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this approach and I can hide some menu entries, like the about dialog of my application using the pattern ".*". When I use the pattern "org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.openFiles" it doesn't hide the open-file menue entry that suddenly appears after resetting and changing the perspective...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, it worked. I just used to wrong ID. When you use the method `hideActionSet` you have to use the ID `org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.openFiles`, but when you want to hide them using activities you have to use `org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.openLocalFile.`

So in conclusion:

- hiding with `hideActionSet`: use `The active contribution item identifier`
- hiding with activities: use `The active action definition identifier`